# Looping for parse txt file that contain many text of some different files

Tags: php, mysql

I have a txt file that contain :

```
===================
INDEXNUMARTICLE: '1'
FILE: 'file1.txt'
===================

3. blablabla
5. bliblibli

===================
INDEXNUMARTICLE: '2'
FILE: 'file2.txt'
===================

1. blublublu
2. blebleble
3. blingblingbling
```

I wanna get the name of file and its contain and save it in database, for example :

```
===============================================
= id = filename   =         contain           =
===============================================
= 1  = file1.txt  = 3. blablabla 5. bliblibli =
= 2  = 'file2.txt = 1. blublublu 2. blebleble =
=                   3. blingblingbling        =
===============================================
```

How to do that? isn't it impossible to get text between FIlE: and FILE:.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using PHPmyadmin, you can create a table within a database to store your data. Using Php, you can connect your database and table to your input and then add the parsed information as individual items. For parsing the .txt file, I believe that you would have to make your own parsing mechanism using php, use an open source parser and include it within your php file or using RegEx (regular expressions).

Comment: I confuse about the looping, when I find the line of name of file, I have to take the contain until the line of another file found